# AWS API Gateway - How to add method to root resource via CLI or GO aws-sdk?

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-sdk, aws-cli, aws-api-gateway, terraform

On the `AWS Console` for `API Gateway` it is possible to add a new `method` to the `root` (`/`) of your `api` without having to add a new resource first.

But I can't figure out how to do that with the `aws cli` or `aws-sdk` (for GO).

Is this even possible?

PS: Eventually I want to do this via `terraform`.

Comment: I'm not sure I follow what you're saying. When you create a new method on an API Gateway you link it to a resource at the same time (even in the console) as actually the method is part of the resource (defining methods is under resources in the AWS console). As such, with Terraform, when creating a new method you must provide the resource that the method is for.

Answer (score 2):

You can achieve it using aws-cli by following the steps.

You can create a new method by `aws apigateway put-method` where following arguments are required: --rest-api-id, --resource-id, --http-method, --authorization-type

Firstly, find your **--rest-api-id** from the json-output to which the method to root resource be added.

```
aws apigateway get-rest-apis
```

The **--resource-id** is the key part here. The root-resource-id of a rest-api can get by the following command which returns a JSON object.

```
aws apigateway get-resources --rest-api-id <restApiId> | jq -r  '.items[0].id'
```

jq is a fast, lightweight, flexible, CLI JSON processor. Visit here for more "http://blog.librato.com/posts/jq-json"

Substitute the values and call the function from CLI.

Example:

```
aws apigateway put-method --rest-api-id hgwwri3w30 --http-method POST --authorization-type NONE --resource-id `aws apigateway get-resources --rest-api-id hgwwri3w30 | jq -r  '.items[0].id'`
```

On success you will get a response like this,

```
{
    "httpMethod": "POST",
    "authorizationType": "NONE",
    "apiKeyRequired": false
}
```

You can setup the method either from the console now or during the function call itself using other parameters.

```
aws apigateway put-method help
```

Answer (score 1):

OK, I think I found the answer at least for `terraform`.

To get the `root resource` we want to add the method to, we can use

`aws_api_gateway_rest_api.ApiName.root_resource_id`

Answer (score 0):

Glad you found the answer for doing this in terraform.

If you want to do this in aws-cli, use [put-method](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/reference/apigateway/put-method.html).

Answer (score 0):

probably a better way to get the *id* of the root path would be:

```
aws apigateway get-resources --rest-api-id <restApiId> --query 'items[?path==`/`]' --output text
```

Then you could write that id to a file `> output.txt` and load it to the `put` method mentioned by [kishor](https://stackoverflow.com/users/6769349/kishor).

Even with Terraform there are sometimes problems with the `root_resource_id` part of the datasource of the aws_api_gateway_rest_api.